# C++ Constructors, Constants, Inheritance and Avoiding Repetition

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, constants, radix

so I've been learning C++ for a few weeks now but I'm having a bit of trouble:

```
Class Tool
{
public:
    Tool(const float maxCarried = 1):maxAmountCarried(maxCarried){}
    virtual void Use() = 0;
    /* ... */
}

Class CuttingTool: public Tool
{
public:
    CuttingTool(const float maxCarried):Tool(maxCarried){}
    virtual void Use(){ /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
}

Class Saw: public CuttingTool
{
public:
    Saw(const float maxCarried):CuttingTool(1){}
    virtual void Use(){ /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
}
Class Scissors: public Fruit
{
public:
    Scissors(const float maxCarried):CuttingTool(2){}
    virtual void Use(){ /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
}
```

A few things to note:

- I'm trying to make a big database of 'Tools'.
- I never change the value of 'maxAmountCarried' so I've set it to const.
- Memory/performance is important because I have a huge vector of Tools.

The problem lies within the fact that I have to keep writing:

`ClassName(const float maxCarried):BaseClass(maxCarried){}`

It's really tedious, moreover, I worry that if I were to add a new const value I would have to repeat the process all over again (problem when you have 50 classes inheriting from Food :S).

I feel as though I've designed this poorly. Is there a way to avoid repeating the same line of code over and over again or do I just have to suck it up and deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need 100 classes inheriting from the Food class?  Doesn't it make more sense for `Food` to just have a property which tells us what type of food it is?  What properties does a `Watermelon` object have that a `PassionFruit` object doesn't have?

Comment: Dammit, you made me hungry.

Comment: Nhgrif, as I did with my previous question, this is just an analogy/example code to make it clear what the problem is. Each class has a totally uses the same functions but the functions themselves are totally different. I suppose I should change the classes to a 'Tools' theme instead.

Comment: Makes me hungry too Joe xD

Comment: The problem with analogies is that they illustrate problems, but people dismiss the problem because 'it is just an analogy'.  If you have 100s of classes, you probably have 100s too many in your design.  If their main difference is a single `double`, I am now relatively certain.  But if all you expose is an analogy, you can dismiss my certainty with 'it is just an analogy'.

Comment: If you are blessed with a C++11 enabled compiler, you would be able to write `class CuttingTool : public Tool { using Tool::Tool; };` Read about [inherited constructors](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting)

Comment: I had a look into Inherited Constructors. Unfortunately Visual Studio (school provides it :P) doesn't support the feature :(. It will definitely be useful if I change compilers/IDEs, thank you Igor Tandetnik.

Comment: Yakk, I see your point. I'd assume that most wouldn't be too keen on reading huge amounts of code, hence the analogy to shorten things down. However, I'm rather impatient so my perception of what is long is a lot shorter than most and I suppose most would be able to comprehend code a lot faster than I would. Would it be better if I were to paste my real code instead? Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only concern is the repeating initialization list you could use a macro like this:

```
#define DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR(Child, Parent) Child(float max) : Parent(max) {}
```

and use it like so:

```
class Saw : public CuttingTool
{
public:
    DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR(Saw, CuttingTool) {}
};
```

You can extend this idea and do something like that:

```
#define BEGIN_CLASS(Child, Parent) class Child : public Parent { \
                                      public: \
                                         Child(float max) : Parent(max) {}

#define END_CLASS };
```

and declare your classes:

```
BEGIN_CLASS(Scissors, Tool)
   void cut_through_paper() {}   // specific method for scissors
END_CLASS
```

Note that there is no point of using `const float` as a parameter since you can't change arguments passed by value anyway. You might however want to use `const float&` to pass an argument by reference, and that will make sense if size of float is bigger than the size of a pointer in your specific platform.

If you never change you max value, you can make it static and share it between all tool instances:

```
class Tool
{
protected:
   static const float _max;
public:
   Tool() {}
};
const float Tool::_max = 0;
```

If you'd like to be able to change max value only once (say at the begining of your program, you can add a static function:

```
static void globalMax(float max) { Tool::_max = max; }
```

and use it where appropriate:

```
int main() {
   Tool::globalMax(5);
   ...
   ...
}
```

Note that you should remove the `const` from the `_max` declaration.

Finally, if performance is an issue, you probably need to rethink your design and maybe go with something else (templates maybe?)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow! That was extremely helpful! I will have a better look into #define (currently only been using them for defining global constants) after this; I'll definitely be using this in the future. Thank you very much!

Comment: I will also look into templates and static constants, thanks again!